# My question is if 0 ≤ a, b < n and a congruent to b mod n, then how is a = b?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I was trying to understand how this works in order to write a proof and I am unable to.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $a\equiv b\pmod n$ means $n|a-b$; i.e., $a-b=kn$.  But if $0\le a,b\lt n$ then $-n<a-b<n$ so $k=0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner how do go from $0\leq a,b<n$ to $-n<a-b<n$? Thank you.

Comment: @manooooh:  I elaborated a bit on that detail in my answer below

Answer (score 1):

$a\equiv b \pmod n$ means $n|a-b$; i.e., $a-b=kn$.

If $0\le a<n$ and $0\le b < n$ (i.e., $-n<-b\le0$) then $-n\lt a-b <n$, so $k=0$, so $a-b=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$b-a$ is a multiple of $n$, yet $b-a\le b-0<n$ and $b-a> b-n\ge 0-n$. Therefore $b-a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition $n$ divides $a-b$, hence $|b-a|$. However $\;0\le |b-a|<n$ if $0\le a,b<n$. How many nonnegative multiples of $n$ which are smaller than $n$ do you know?